# How to check if dbms_refresh.refresh() has finished?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, refresh, materialized-views

I have in Oracle 11g R2 a refresh group composed by three materialized views. I use a Java/JDBC program to refresh the group:

```
....
Statement s1 = conn.createStatement();    
String sql="begin dbms_refresh.refresh('<refresh_group_name>');end;";
s1.execute(sql);
```

After that, in the same program I need to execute additional operations; these operation must be executed after dbms_refresh.refresh() has finished its work. Even if I am not sure, I suspect that dbms_refresh.refresh() works asynchronously; so, one option is to check if dbms_refresh.refresh() has finished, then wait some time and check again in a loop.
So, the questions are: how can I check if dbms_refresh.refresh() has finished refreshing all the materialized views in the refresh group? Does dbms_refresh.refresh() really works asynchronously?

Thanks